# Reset While loop value in PHP

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a php loop, but it keeps printing the value next to each other instead of clearing the first loop value and replacing it with the new loop value. Here is my code.

```
   while (1==1) {
        $a=array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");
        $x=array_rand($a,3);
        sleep(5);
        print $a[$x[0]]; 
   }
```

Basically it just needs to echo out a new random value on its own every 5 seconds, currently it doesn't remove the old value.

Comment: From what I understand, this can't be done via PHP. As PHP does it's thing and sends that data over to the user. It can't clear what it has already sent. You would need something client side like JavaScript to change the value that the user already sees.

Comment: The only way this will behave as you want is in the terminal window and you would need to return to the beginning of the line: `print $a[$x[0]]."\r";` and account for some words being longer than others: `print $a[$x[0]] . str_repeat(" ", 3) . "\r";`

Comment: Why should it remove the previous value? "print" means "print", not "remove whatever was there before and then print"

Comment: It would be better to do `$x=array_rand($a);` and `print $a[$x] . PHP_EOL;` as you are not actually using the 3 random value you are only using one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use jquery, the below example is for random numbers.

```
<script>

    var id = window.setInterval(function(){randomNumber();},1000);

    function randomNumber()
    {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        //Do whatever you want with that number
        $('#holder').html(rand);
    }

</script>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Random Number</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id='holder'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For random text

```
var names = ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'];

setInterval(function() {
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = names[rand];
}, 2000);

<div id="name">test</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if i understand what you are trying to accomplish, but I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
$a=array("red","green","blue","yellow","brown");
while (count($a)) {

        $x=array_rand($a);
        sleep(5);
        echo chr(13). $a[$x];

}
```